# Running in circles with errors trying to git push heroku master and yarn

Tags: reactjs, git, heroku, npm, yarnpkg

I've been trying for 2 days to deploy my Rails/React app to Heroku and it's been a nightmare. I think I finally have the Rails side up but the React side is nothing but grief. The latest issue is a problem with `yarn`. I've tried to upgrade it. I updated npm, node, etc.

The issue is then I try to `git push heroku master`. I get the following errors which is the ending of many `warning resolution incompatible` errors.

```
emote:        warning Resolution field "whatwg-url@6.5.0" is incompatible with requested version "whatwg-url@^7.0.0"
remote:        error Your lockfile needs to be updated, but yarn was run with `--frozen-lockfile`.
remote:        info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote: 
remote:  !     Outdated Yarn lockfile
remote: 
remote:        Your application contains a Yarn lockfile (yarn.lock) which does not
remote:        match the dependencies in package.json. This can happen if you use npm
remote:        to install or update a dependency instead of Yarn.
remote: 
remote:        Please run the following command in your application directory and check
remote:        in the new yarn.lock file:
remote: 
remote:        $ yarn install
remote:        $ git add yarn.lock
remote:        $ git commit -m "Updated Yarn lockfile"
remote:        $ git push heroku master
remote:     
remote:        https://kb.heroku.com/why-is-my-node-js-build-failing-because-of-an-outdated-yarn-lockfile
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile React.js (create-react-app) multi app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to faunagram-app.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/faunagram-app.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/faunagram-app.git'
```

Here's what my `package-json` file looks like:

```
{
  "name": "faunagram-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "fsevents": "^2.0.6",
    "ip-locator": "0.0.1",
    "iplocation": "^6.1.0",
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-activestorage-provider": "^0.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "react-geolocated": "^2.4.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.4.0-beta.7",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.86.0",
    "yarn": "^1.16.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "description": "An informative and social media app for all things urban wildlife. As our urban centers have cleaned up through the years, many animal species are returning. This app allows for people to share sightings of these creatures. See video DEMO here. Screenshot",
  "main": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "repository": "git+https://github.com/dsound-zz/faunagram-frontend.git",
  "author": "Demian Sims",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/dsound-zz/faunagram-frontend/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/dsound-zz/faunagram-frontend#readme",
  "resolutions": {
    "fsevents": "1.2.9",
    "doctrine": "3.0.0",
    "resolve": "1.1.7",
    "js-tokens": "3.0.2",
    "debug": "2.6.9",
    "ms": "2.0.0",
    "tough-cookie": "2.5.0",
    "punycode": "1.3.2",
    "extsprintf": "1.4.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.4.3",
    "regenerator-runtime": "0.11.1",
    "path-to-regexp": "0.1.7",
    "core-js": "2.6.5",
    "promise": "8.0.2",
    "iconv-lite": "0.4.23",
    "isarray": "1.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "7.4.4",
    "camelcase": "4.1.0",
    "fs-extra": "4.0.3",
    "jest-resolve": "24.8.0",
    "semver": "5.5.0",
    "json5": "1.0.1",
    "source-map": "0.6.1",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "ansi-styles": "2.2.1",
    "supports-color": "2.0.0",
    "color-name": "1.1.4",
    "jsesc": "0.5.0",
    "minimist": "0.0.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-classes": "7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring": "7.4.4",
    "browserslist": "4.5.4",
    "cosmiconfig": "4.0.0",
    "import-fresh": "2.0.0",
    "parse-json": "2.2.0",
    "resolve-from": "3.0.0",
    "callsites": "2.0.0",
    "esprima": "3.1.3",
    "is-arrayish": "0.3.2",
    "vfile": "3.0.1",
    "parse5": "4.0.0",
    "is-buffer": "1.1.6",
    "unist-util-stringify-position": "1.1.2",
    "vfile-message": "1.1.1",
    "clone-deep": "0.2.4",
    "kind-of": "3.2.2",
    "for-own": "0.1.5",
    "lazy-cache": "0.2.7",
    "shallow-clone": "0.1.2",
    "for-in": "0.1.8",
    "isobject": "2.1.0",
    "is-extendable": "1.0.1",
    "css-select": "2.0.2",
    "css-tree": "1.0.0-alpha.29",
    "domutils": "1.7.0",
    "eslint-scope": "4.0.3",
    "slash": "1.0.0",
    "normalize-path": "2.1.1",
    "readable-stream": "3.3.0",
    "inherits": "2.0.1",
    "string_decoder": "1.1.1",
    "pump": "2.0.1",
    "string-width": "1.0.2",
    "strip-ansi": "3.0.1",
    "is-fullwidth-code-point": "1.0.0",
    "ansi-regex": "2.1.1",
    "define-property": "0.2.5",
    "extend-shallow": "2.0.1",
    "is-descriptor": "0.1.6",
    "is-accessor-descriptor": "0.1.6",
    "is-data-descriptor": "0.1.4",
    "has-value": "0.3.1",
    "set-value": "0.4.3",
    "has-values": "0.1.4",
    "find-up": "2.1.0",
    "locate-path": "2.0.0",
    "p-locate": "2.0.0",
    "path-exists": "3.0.0",
    "p-limit": "1.3.0",
    "p-try": "1.0.0",
    "read-pkg-up": "4.0.0",
    "require-main-filename": "2.0.0",
    "read-pkg": "3.0.0",
    "load-json-file": "4.0.0",
    "path-type": "3.0.0",
    "pify": "2.3.0",
    "find-cache-dir": "0.1.1",
    "pkg-dir": "2.0.0",
    "postcss-selector-parser": "3.1.1",
    "cssesc": "2.0.0",
    "ignore": "3.3.10",
    "inquirer": "6.2.2",
    "acorn": "5.7.3",
    "mimic-fn": "1.2.0",
    "wordwrap": "0.0.3",
    "commander": "2.17.1",
    "uglify-js": "3.5.12",
    "yargs": "12.0.5",
    "jsdom": "11.12.0",
    "whatwg-url": "6.5.0",
    "ws": "5.2.2",
    "decamelize": "1.2.0",
    "yargs-parser": "11.1.1",
    "address": "1.1.0",
    "globby": "6.1.0",
    "opn": "5.5.0",
    "is-glob": "3.1.0",
    "faye-websocket": "0.10.0",
    "mime": "1.4.1",
    "util": "0.10.3",
    "array-flatten": "1.1.1",
    "statuses": "1.5.0"
  }
}
```

There's also a yarn error file:

```
Arguments: 
  /Users/demiansims/.nvm/versions/node/v12.2.0/bin/node /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.16.0/libexec/bin/yarn.js install

PATH: 
  /Users/demiansims/.nvm/versions/node/v12.2.0/bin:/Users/demiansims/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/bin:/Users/demiansims/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0@global/bin:/Users/demiansims/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/usr/local:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/local:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/demiansims/.rvm/bin

Yarn version: 
  1.16.0

Node version: 
  12.2.0

Platform: 
  darwin x64

Trace: 
  SyntaxError: /Users/demiansims/Development/Faunagram/Faunagram-frontend/package.json: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 161
      at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
      at /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.16.0/libexec/lib/cli.js:1625:59
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at step (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.16.0/libexec/lib/cli.js:304:30)
      at /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.16.0/libexec/lib/cli.js:315:13

npm manifest: 
  {
    "name": "vulture",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "vulture",
    "main": "index.js",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
      "start": "node index.js",
    },
    "author": "vulture",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
      "node": "8.4.0",
      "npm": "5.4.0"
    }
  }

yarn manifest: 
  No manifest

Lockfile: 
  No lockfile
```

I've tried following the instructions listed in the error but keeps coming back to this. I also had a problem with installing yarn with something called `fsevents` having a problem with the version of node I'm using. I `brew updated node` to fix that (I think). Sorry to be a pain but this is my first attempt at deploying an app and it's been nothing but hell. Seems like it shouldn't be this difficult.

Comment: Do you have the `yarn.lock` file for your project check in version control? If you don't have one, run `yarn install` to generate one and check it into git before pushing to heroku

Comment: Ok I tried that but still getting all these warning compatibility errors and that final message to install yarn, etc. I've tried so many combinations of things I'm just wondering if there's a way to start completely from scratch and if there's a solid deploy to Heroku tutorial out there. These Medium articles are all over the place.

Comment: What does "I've tried to upgrade it. I updated npm, node, etc." mean? What are the exact commands you ran, and where did you run them?

Comment: I've tried running `npm install`, `npm update`, `yarn install`, `yarn update`. Also `npm install yarn` and `npm install g yarn`